# Import Windows 2008R2 .p12 certificate into Samba4 SDC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, openldap, samba4

In our firm we need to migrate our existing infrastructure from Windows 2008R2 to Samba 4. To do this we already managed to add the Samba machine as a secondary domain controller. The next step would be to import the 2008R2 CA into Samba. I managed to export a .p12 file containing both the private and public keys and I tried to import them in the new DC in this way:

Generate the private key:

```
# openssl pkcs12 -in ca.p12 -nocerts -out priv.pem
# openssl rsa -in priv.pam -out priv.pem
```

Generate the public key:

```
# openssl pkcs12 -in ca.p12 -out privpub.pem
# openssl x509 -inform pem -in privpub.pem -pubkey -out pub.pem -outform pem
```

Move the keys in their final location:

```
# cp *.pem /var/lib/samba/private/tls
# chmod 600 /var/lib/samba/private/tls/priv.pem
```

Configure smb.conf:

```
tls enabled  = yes
tls keyfile  = tls/priv.pem
tls certfile = tls/pub.pem
tls cafile   =
```

However, when I try to connect from a CentOS 6 client through LDAP:

```
# ldapsearch -x -d -1 -D ldapuser@mydomain.loc -W
```

I get this:

TLS: certificate [...] is not valid - error -8102:Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation..

Sorry if the question is dumb, but I'm not really into SSL certificates unfortunately

Thanks for any input